# How to change the number for the default "Number of Rows and Columns" when we create a new Table in Pages?

Tags: macos, monterey, pages, settings

When I try to add a new Table in **Pages** (v13.0) on **MacOS 12.6.5** (I chose the bottom-left one), it automatically creates a table with **5 rows** and **4 columns** (as seen in the second image). How do I edit this default value of Rows & Columns to populate ?

Say, I want to create a table with only **1 Row** and **2 Columns**, how do I do it, without changing it each time from the **Format** menu, on the right.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the preferences?

Comment: @SolarMike Can you specify what to check in Preferences? I have checked the Menu bar items, and haven't found a solution from there. I have also tried to search online, but no luck.

Comment: Are you on iPhone? What iOS version are you running?

Comment: @Thinkr , I have editted the question, to add more context.

Comment: That's a nice edit, +1

Comment: This is not possible through regular Pages or macOS settings.  Perhaps this can be accomplished by hacking some `plist` file but I even doubt that. I think your best would be to make a feature suggestion to Apple through their feedback webpage.

Comment: As suggested by @Alper, I have created a feature request, to the Pages team.